# How to include serious personal project in Resume?

Tags: resume

My brother has come up with an interesting business idea that could be commercialised. For over a month I have been creating the foundation for SaaS. I have been treating this as commercial project so designing using patterns and best practices.

One of the reasons I want to include this in my Resume is my full time job doesn't involve current trendy ASP.Net technologies (e.g Linq/Entity Relationships, jQuery, ASP.Net MVC 3, Silverlight, etc) so the resume lacks impact. In my full time job I work on a 7 year old well designed product and since our data and web layers work well it would be stupid to re-engineer them only because recruiters think Linq, ASP.Net MVC and jQuery are cool.

How can I include my personal project in Resume so that it doesn't sound like experiment or quick'n'dirty pet project?

Comment: Same way you include anything else on your resume?  Explain the project and put up a demo if you can?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What's so bad about an experiment? I love resumes that demonstrate the candidate is actively experimenting. As far as quick 'n dirty, you'll prove it isn't by continuing to work on it. Take it from a great idea to a great product. Polish, polish, polish. You can show it's not amateurish by, well, not acting like an amateur. Take the project seriously and you'll be fine. Specific ideas:

- Include it with your other experience (after you've worked on it for more than a month). Many people list simultaneous jobs on their resume, especially if they're consultants. Consider it the start of your own new business.
- Include a link to your github or bitbucket repositories. This allows the curious to see the project as a living and growing thing. They'll notice your perseverance and professionalism.
- Add a "personal passions" block to your resume. Talk about your project. Explain why it's important. Show that you're not including it because the technologies are "trendy". Show that you're including it because you believe in it and believe the technologies are powerful and better than the alternatives.

Comment: Nothing bad about experiment per say. I just thought hiring managers would not take it serious.

Comment: By including it as part of your resume it will show you have a passion for programming that extends outside of work